# Is there a way to generate a Realm.io database from a Windows server?

Tags: java, mobile, xamarin, realm, realm-net

I would like to generate a Realm.io database from a windows server. My aim is to download it (through web services) and read it from a mobile device (iOS).

So is there a way to generate a Realm.io database from a Windows server through a console application ?

I tried to do so with Xamarin Studio and a Console Application project but i had a System.PlatformNotSupportedException as PC platform seems to not be supported yet (https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/issues/509).

I thought to do that in java too but Realm.io seems to "not support Java outside of Android at the moment" (https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/).

Is there a trick to do what i want with Xamarin or Java ?

Is there any other way ?

Comment: Why not generate the data as json or something and populate the realm on the device? Why should your server care what database library your client uses?

Comment: We need to generate database server side in order to optimise the time to populate it. Data insertion is slower on mobile devices than on the server, specially if the amount of data is important. And if you share the same datas between multiple users, you just need to generate data one time.

Comment: Plus if you start with an encrypted Realm on the server, you never have an unencrypted copy of a file on the device. (Yes I know if you directly consumed JSON over https it would be encrypted directly into the program.)

Answer (score 1):

As of August 2016, sorry, no we do not have support for Windows servers.

We have an [open issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/issues/721) for voting on *plain* Windows support.

[Issue 509](https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/issues/509) is for voting on different flavours of UWP.

Comment: You can from a Mac though using Swift or ObjC :-)

Comment: And just in case anyone thinks about getting creative with cross-platform Swift, no that wouldn't currently work either as the core library is native - if we had one ready to ship on Windows we would already be supporting it in C#. ;-)

Comment: @bmunk In fact we already use objective-c to generate the CoreData from a Mac. But we need to find a solution from a Windows system...